# export fails to properly expose android sdk directory

Tags: android, macos, cordova, export

This is probably a stupid question, and I wouldn't be surprised if someone tagged it as either irrelevant, or "does not show minimal understanding of the problem", but I am at my wit's end and cannot find a possible solution.

I am trying to use the PhoneGap library to develop Android apps on Mac. According to PhoneGap's docs, I need to have the android command available in my PATH environment variable, which I set up by creating a .bash_profile file and adding an export command.

I have added this to my .bash_profile:

```
export PATH=${PATH}:~/Downloads/android-sdk-mac_x86/tools/
```

I can guarantee that the android command does, indeed, exist in that path. I close and reopen the Terminal, type "android", and I get a "command not found error".  I also get this when I try to run the command:

```
$phonegap local build android
```

Typing "export" alone on the Terminal shows me that, indeed, the path specified in the .bash_profile was added to the PATH variable, so how come it still can't find the "android" command? Thanks for any info!

Answer (score 0):

Try the following command after you save your changes to .bash_profile:

source  ~/.bash_profile

This will load the values immediately without having to reboot.